# How to call changeNotifier from callback function? Flutter

Tags: flutter, callback, flutter-provider

I call a function from the build function in my Flutter app.
When I call `notifyListeners();` from an async callback function I get the following exception:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

My Provider:

```
class TechTaskProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ...
  void requestTasks() {
   
    CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> _collection =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('techTasks')
            .doc(_currentTech!.uid)
            .collection('techTasks');

    _collection.get().then((s) {
        _handleResult(s);
        notifyListeners();
    });
}
```

My Trigger widget:

```
class Trigger extends StatefulWidget {
  const Trigger({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Trigger> createState() => _TriggerState();
}

class _TriggerState extends State<Trigger> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyProvider _myProv = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context);
    //
    if (isFirstRun) {
      //Set the first techincian:
      isFirstRun = false;
      // //Trigger Firestore request:
      _myProv.requestTasks();
    }
    return Page();
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to determine where are you calling `setState`, because it's probably called during rebuild and that forces another rebuild which results in inifite loop. Message below your error should also contain the part where it says which widget called `setState` (e.g. of that message `The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: Widget name here`)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
class _TriggerState extends State<Trigger> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyProvider _myProv = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context);
    //
    if (isFirstRun) {
      //Set the first techincian:
      isFirstRun = false;
      // //Trigger Firestore request:
      WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _myProv.requestTasks());

    }
    return Page();
  }
}
```